# Adding bootstrap to webpack bundle of angular2-seed project

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

I want use bootstrap in this Angular2 seed project: https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed

How can I achieve this?
It is already added in the package.json but e.g. using "class="btn btn-default" will have no effect.

I tried adding `require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');` in `vendor.browser.js` without effect.

Answer (score 0):

After adding in package.json, do an npm install and reference the link in index.html from node_modules:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css/">
```

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified: I want it included in the bundle bundled by webpack. I should not touch index.html.

Comment: why? I don't understand what the advantage is

Answer (score 0):

I just had to figure this out, so figured I'd share:

In `tools/config/project.config.ts`, add the following line inside the `this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES` assignment array:

```
{src: 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
```

And add the following line inside the `this.APP_ASSETS` assignment array:

```
{src: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', inject: true, vendor: false},
```

Full example:

```
this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
  ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
  {src: 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
];

// Add `local` third-party libraries to be injected/bundled.
this.APP_ASSETS = [
  ...this.APP_ASSETS,
  {src: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', inject: true, vendor: false},
];
```